# Filter the data from the SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, filtering

In the below table, I need to exclude `CategoryID=1002` and `Gender='KIDS'` record from the table and return other records.

```
+------+--------+
|  ID  | Gender |
+------+--------+
| 1001 | MENS   |
| 1002 | MENS   |
| 1001 | WOMENS |
| 1002 | WOMENS |
| 1001 | KIDS   |
| 1002 | KIDS   |
+------+--------+
```

Expected results:

```
+------+--------+
|  ID  | Gender |
+------+--------+
| 1001 | MENS   |
| 1002 | MENS   |
| 1001 | WOMENS |
| 1002 | WOMENS |
| 1001 | KIDS   |
+------+--------+
```

Comment: What did you try? Did ever try to use `WHERE` clause?

Comment: I have tried but I want it in single query

Comment: add multiple condition with and operator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't recommend using `case` expressions in the `where` clause, because that can affect the optimizer.

This is easily expressed as boolean logic:

```
where not (CategoryID = 1002 and Gender = 'KIDS')
```

or:

```
where CategoryID <> 1002 or Gender <> 'KIDS'
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `CASE` expression as

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
  VALUES
  (1001,    'MENS'),
  (1002,    'MENS'),
  (1001,    'WOMENS'),
  (1002,    'WOMENS'),
  (1001,    'KIDS'),
  (1002,    'KIDS')
) T(Id, Gender)
WHERE CASE WHEN ID = 1002 AND Gender = 'KIDS' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END = 0;
```

**[Online Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=535a748023b2f48afba2070e13e6c9d4)**